# Something always promised, never fully realized

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm searching for a term or phrase for something which is always promised but never delivered. The way nuclear fusion is always 10 years away. Or how companies keep making jet packs, but never sell them.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on what nuance you want to give the phrase "The search for the **ever-elusive/mythical/pie-in-the-sky/much promised/perpetually immanent/etc.,** jet pack/fusion reactor."

Comment: Nuclear fusion is a **pipe dream**.

Comment: @Greybeard that as an answer gets it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what nuance you want to give the phrase. A lot will depend on contest but, broadly:

"The search for the **ever-elusive** jet pack/fusion reactor." Gives the idea that there may be some hope for the product appearing at some time in the future

"The search for the **mythical** jet pack/fusion reactor." Somewhat dismissive in view of earlier attempts/claims/promises.

"The search for **pie-in-the-sky** jet pack/fusion reactor." Quite dismissive: the writer does not believe either will appear.

"The search for **much promised** jet pack/fusion reactor." More factual but cautious as to whether this version will work/sell.

"The search for the **perpetually imminent** jet pack/fusion reactor." Recognises that there have been many previous claims that something will appear in the very near future.

Comment: +1 for so many words. By the way, should it be _immanent_ or _imminent_? :)

Comment: You're right - give yourself +10... :)

Answer (score 2):

***blue sky***

> not grounded in the realities of the present

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blue-sky)

> using the imagination to think of ideas that do not yet have practical uses or make money:

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blue-sky)

Sustainable nuclear fusion is ***"blue sky"*** thinking. It is visionary, but still beyond current technology.

Companies keep making jet packs, but never sell them. They don't make money on a visionary ***blue sky*** idea.

Comment: Hmm... This is very close, but has a positive context. I was thinking of a more negative tilt. This gets me close though.